# how to remove specified rows of a table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onchange, show-hide, tablerow

I have a table with a header and some rows. Each row has its own group, and sometimes they could be similar with the previous group codes.
Also, I have a drop-down list that contains groups IDs. I want to show just the rows that are equal with the drop-down list current value.
For example this is my table `id="myTable"`:
[image]

and this is my drop-down:

```
<select id="groups" name="groups">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I need to remove 2nd and 3rd row when user change the current selected item of drop-down to 1.
How can I do it using jQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("#groups").change(function() {
    var currentGroup = $(this).val();
    $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
       if (this.rowIndex==0) return; // skip heading
       if ($(this).children("td").eq(-1).text() == currentGroup)
          $(this).show();
       else
          $(this).hide();
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DBCcF/1/

You could simplify the JS by giving the cells in the third column a particular class, but then I guess that complicates the markup, so...whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#groups").on("change", function() {
    var rowNum = $(this).val();
    $("#myTable tr")
        .show()
        .each(function() {
            var $this = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)");
            if ($this.text() !== rowNum) {
                $this.closest("tr").hide();
            }
        });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/gUjtj/).

This will check the value of the selected element against the content of every third cell in every row. If it doesn't match, it hides it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. The easiest is going to require a small change to the table structure as we need a way of looking up groupid in the table. What you could do is just add a class to the cells that contain a groupid like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td class='groupId'>1</td>
</tr>
```

Then you would write your javascript similar to the other answers except you would not need to use inflexible techniques like `nth-child(3)` or `eq(-1)`. This would make the javascript more flexible to change.

You could end up with something like this:

```
function hideRows(){
    // find selected value (get only the first as multi-selected is not required)
    var selected = $('#groups option:selected')[0].value;
    // walk through all cells that have the groupId class
    $('#myTable td.groupId').each(function(){
        // get current cell
        var currentCell = $(this);
        // get the cells groupid
        var groupid = currentCell.text();
        // determine if it the group id matches the selected value and hide/show
        if(groupid !== selected){
            currentCell.parent().hide();
        }
        else{
            currentCell.parent().show();
        }
    }); 
}
// wire-up select change event
$('#groups').change(hideRows);
```

Without some way to isolate the groupid cells in the table you will need to resort to one of the aforementioned techniques to aquire the correct column.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GFzcp/5/